Do most aircraft have a ditch button in the case of emergency?
In the ditching of US Airways Flight 1549 in 2009, the pilots did not have time to press the "ditch" button present on the Airbus aircraft they were flying. In other circumstances where time permits, the "ditch" button may help slow the rate of flooding if the aircraft remained intact after impact. The "ditch" button seals off all valves, inlets, and opening underneath the aircraft, to prevent water from entering through these places. My question is, do all large, commercial aircraft have this button? For example, do Boeing 737, 747, 767, 777, and 787 have this switch? Thanks for any help!
image of the ditch button on the Airbus A330 from Wikipedia

Format your text!

@Cloud Can you please tell me how to format my text? Which part do you think should be re-formatted? My content isn't too long, so do you think I still need to separate them into two paragraphs? Thanks for suggestions!

Can downvoter please tell me how to improve? I'll appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance!  :)

I've only ever seen this button on Airbus aircraft.
It's hard to prove a negative, but as an example here is the ditching checklist for a Boeing 777, where the outflow valves are closed manually and no ditching button is involved:

Ditching
Condition: Airplane ditching and evacuation are needed.

Plan to jettison fuel as needed to reduce VREF speeds.
Checklist Complete Except Deferred Items

Deferred Items
Below 5,000 feet
GND PROX GEAR OVRD switch ... OVRD
GND PROX TERR OVRD switch ... OVRD
PACK switches (both) ... Off
OUTFLOW VALVE switches (both) ... MAN
OUTFLOW VALVE MANUAL switches (both) ... Hold in CLOSE until the outflow valve indications show fully closed [...]
On final approach (omit Landing checklist)
Landing gear lever ... UP
Flaps ... 30

(Boeing 777 QRH - 0.1 Ditching)
For reference, on the Airbus A320 the ditching button closes more than just the outflow valve:

The operating system sends a "close" signal to the outflow valve, emergency ram air inlet, avionics ventilation inlet and extract valves, and pack flow control valves.

(Airbus A320 FCOM - Air Conditioning and Pressurization - Pressurization - DITCHING guarded pushbutton)

Thanks for your answer! So basically only Airbus integrated all these procedures into one simple button. I think other aircraft should have this too because time is extremely crucial in emergency situations and needing to spend precious seconds in manually closing valves and stuff defers the start of the actual ditching as well as distracting the pilots. Apparently, Airbus did a great job on this.

@AircraftEnthusiast007, as with many safety things having this as a single control also means a single fault, software error, mis press or other issue can trigger a whole bunch of events that turn an otherwise safe flight into a complicated emergency, so is not an automatic win. See for example helicopter ejector seats which require having a method to deliberately remove the rotor system.

@AircraftEnthusiast007, ditchings of jet airliners are extremely rare -- about one a decade.  Ditchings on short notice are even less common: US Airways 1549 is the only one I've been able to find.  Optimizing for extremely rare events is generally not a good idea.

@Mark And ditchings of large aircraft generally go very badly anyway.  1549 was special in that they could ditch in a river rather than a large body of water and thus had a much lower threat from waves.

The comments miss a point: the Airbus ditch switch isn't just for ditching. Its most common used purpose is to seal the aircraft when deicing to prevent fluid ingestion, as well as some maintenance tests. It's marked for ditching because that's the most safety and time-critical use. Optimizing for the most critical use of a control is a important human factors concept.

@GremlinWranger I agree with you that in many cases integrating too much into a single button/switch may not be the best choice since it can be a mistake. But in this case I don't see how closing valves and openings can cause too much trouble even if it is not intended. Even if it does cause trouble, then it would've been relatively easy to solve. In comparison, if an aircraft is really going for an emergency  ditching, having such a button would save the pilots' precious seconds before impact. Thus, I think having this functionality would be better than not having it.
